# xsl template match don't work when xml header provided

Tags: xslt

I try to merge 2 web.xml based on explanation founds on this site but i have a problem.

If my inputs files starts with a simple header as describe below, all is ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app> <!-- no schema information here -->
   <servlet id="identifier">
      ...
   </servlet>
</web-app>
```

but, if i use an input file like this, the **match** don't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

   <servlet id="identifier">
      ...
   </servlet>
</web-app>
```

The xsl template match i used is this one.

```
<xsl:template name="main" match="/web-app/servlet[@id='identifier']">
```

Have you any issue ?

Thanks for your help.

edit: I'm using saxon 8.7

Comment: Do a search for *namespace*.

Comment: we had issues saxon 9|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saxon 8.7 is an XSLT 2.0 processor, so you should be able to include:

```
xpath-default-namespace="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
```

in your `xsl:stylesheet` open tag to make your template's `match` expression (and all your other XPath expressions) address the elements of your XML - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames

Comment: Thx a lot @michael-hor257k, `xpath-default-namespace` works perfectly.